# Apache Ignite - Rest API timestamp format

Tags: ignite

I have upgraded Ignite 2.7.6 on Java 8 to Ignite 2.13 on Java 11.
In the REST API response the timestamp format has changed.
Locale and all other ENV variables on the host are equal.

Is there a possibility to define the format of the timestamp output in the
Ignite configuration?

Example of timestamp data, difference is in "," after year.

Ignite 2.7.6 Java 8 -> "Sep 18, 2019 12:57:35 PM"

Ignite 2.13 Java 11 -> "Aug 31, 2022, 12:43:44 PM"

Comment: What Java data type is your timestamp field? When I use `java.sql.Timestamp`, I get a date in ISO format (`1970-01-20 06:57:58.558`).

Comment: {"schemaName":"PUBLIC","typeName":"ALERTS_REPORTER","fieldName":"ALARMCLEAREDTIME","fieldTypeName":"java.sql.Timestamp"}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the default locale provider change in the Java 9+, see  [JEP 252](https://openjdk.org/jeps/252).

As a workaround, you can set the next option to enable behavior compatible with Java 8:

```
-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor Belyakov, i have tested on Ignite 2.13.0 and JAVA 11. Timespamp format is now exact as on Java 8.